# How can i limit records to be synched to some limit using Microsoft sync framework

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

This is regarding Microsoft sync framework where we are syncing Ipad data with Sql server database.
It is working fine.

But here, I want to limit my records to be synched to only 20 records at a time. Right now, all the records are getting synched.
I there a out-of box feature by sync framework which will enable us to do so.

If not, how can I write a custom code to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to set batching.  but it's in terms of size, not number of rows. you can simply get your row size and multiply by the number of rows you have in mind.

lookup SetDownloadBatchSize and SetBatchSpoolDirectory in the documentation.

e.g. config.SetDownloadBatchSize = some value in Kb